# Bad encoding characters in Android TextView

Tags: java, android, json, character-encoding, textview

I have a problem with the display phone number in TextView. The application receives data from REST service in json format encoded in utf-8. Spaces and hyphens are displayed like this:

[image]

If I write the data in logcat, characters are displayed correctly.What could be the problem?

P.S. I use custom font, but this problem remains in standard font.

Comment: Did you check the character codes and make sure they were correct?  A 32 for space and 45 for dash?  Because normally this is a problem of the font not having the correct characters, so lets make sure you're sending down what you think you are.  Logcat doesn't help here because it will be displayed in your PC's font.

Comment: remove custom font from textview n check value.

Comment: So, I checked the code of dash symbol and it's 8210. I solved the problem just by replacing 8210 by 45